# will httpclient use system proxy by default (clojure)?

Tags: clojure, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using clojure httpclient library. And I also set the system proxy, also in my mint OS I have set http_proxy. So when I use clojure httpclient, will it use these proxy? Or if I don't specify any proxy in the code, then it won't use any proxy?

Comment: Which client? Can you link it? clj-http is configurable. Just search for "proxy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are using [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http), it will not use system proxy, it has defaults set. But if you'd like to use a specific proxy, modify it using this function `make-socks-proxied-conn-manager`.

Read more - [Proxies in clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http/blob/18fcb0165302463769dc449f40451779afee4fef/README.org#proxies)

Comment: Yes I am using clj-http. I am using lantern (https://github.com/getlantern/lantern) as system proxy. My app ran well when lantern is running, but failed when lantern is shutdown. I didn't specify any proxy related parameter in my code. So I thought there must be some default setting which will depends on the setting of the operation system (OS). The error is "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused"